# Why would the diameter of a subset of a metric space not be finite?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The diameter of a subset $A$ of metric space $(X,d)$ is defined as

$\delta(A)=\sup_{x,y\in A}d(x,y)$

and the set $A$ is defined as bounded if $\delta(A)<\infty$. But, since the first axiom of metric space says that the metric should be finite. Does not it mean that every metric space should be bounded?
Seeing the comments below, I think my understanding of the concept is supremum and boundedness is not quite right. I am reading functional analysis from Kreyszig's 'Introductory functional analysis'. I don't have a background in real analysis. I will be helpful if someone can answer this questions with some explanation of these concepts.

Comment: What would you say the diameter of $\mathbb{R}$ is?

Comment: Each d is finite. The supremum can still be infinite.

Comment: If $A$ has an infinite number of elements, you take an infinite set of real quantities and their "supremum" can perfectly be $\infty$.

Comment: @eric That is sort of my doubt? Since the diameter of $R$ can reach $\infty$, it implies that $d(x,y)$ is not finite for some $x$ and $y$; then how is it s valid metric space?

Comment: @Ian isn't the supremum just a d?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is definitely a metric space which is not finite. I can't recall any such axiom

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Your deduction is not correct. Being unbounded is not the same as there exist 2 elements $x,y$ whose distance between them is infinity.

Comment: @Jean I don't understand this fact. may be I don't understand the concept of supremum.

Comment: Consider the infinite set $A=\mathbb Z$ considered as a subset of $\mathbb R$ (with its usual metric), the diameter of $A$ is the sup of all $|i-j|$ which can be **any** positive integer value, thus this sup is $\infty$.

Comment: The supremum of a set can be one of the values in the set or not. In particular, the supremum of a set that is not bounded above like $[0,\infty)$ is infinite even though all its values separately are finite.

Comment: @MathMan First axiom of metric space requires the metric to be finite.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Then what does it imply?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Consider this closely related statement: The supremum of $\Bbb N$ is infinity, while every element of $\Bbb N$ is finite. Why is this NOT contradictory?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with metric space per se, I'd suggest that you review the definition of upper bound and supremum.

Comment: @ BigbearZZz yeah! I feel I should do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, any specific distance $d(x,y)$ must be finite. This follows from the definition of $d$ as a function from $X\times X$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$ ($+\infty \notin \mathbb{R}^+$).

But the diameter of a set $A$ is a supremum of infinitely many real numbers (if $A$ is infinite), namely all distances between the different points from $A$. And a supremum of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$ *can* be $+\infty$: e.g. in the reals, usual metric, if $A = \mathbb{N}$ for $\delta(A)$ we have to find the supremum of $\{d(n,m); n,m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ which contains $\{d(0,n)= n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \mathbb{N}$. And $\sup(\mathbb{N}) = +\infty$ as there is no upperbound in the reals for the set $\mathbb{N}$.

So $\delta(A) = +\infty$ is just saying that there is no upperbound $B \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $d(a,a') \le B$ for all $a,a' \in A$.

A supremum is often not a maximum: if $A = (0,1)$, then $\delta(A) = 1$ even when there are no $x,y \in A$ with $d(x,y) = 1$. But we take the sup of real numbers like $d(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}) = 1-\frac{2}{n}$ which can approach $1$ as closely as you like, taking larger and larger $n$. And it's certainly not a maximum for trivial reasons if $\delta(A) = +\infty$, as we saw.